# May somebody help with interpretation of trees from h2o.gbm, see as photo attached

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, boosting, h2o

This picture is from h2o.gbm, while I'm not sure how to interpret the numbers in it.

1. What is the big title "Class NO" mean? Does it mean the root node is labeled "No"? Or does it mean this tree is giving the probability of classifying as "No"?
2. What is the meaning of the numbers in leaf node? For example, "-0.013380057", is it the logodds? Since it cannot be the probability.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- What is the big title "Class NO" mean?

**By default for a binary classification problem GBM will only build trees to predict one class, so Class No means you are seeing a tree that is trying to predict "NO" (I'm guessing your response column is binary and composed of YES or NO").**

- What is the meaning of the numbers in leaf node?

**These are the corrections. GBM builds sequential trees where each tree is built on the residuals of the former and the first tree is build on an initialized residual vector, which is based on the distribution of your target. Please see this resource for more information on how the initial value and terminal nodes are calculated: http://www.saedsayad.com/docs/gbm2.pdf.**

- For example, "-0.013380057", is it the logodds? Since it cannot be
  the probability.

**This is the correction (or predicted value of the single tree where it is trying to predict the residuals of the former), which is why you can see negative values.**

Answer (score 0):

Tree 0 is your main model tree.

The leaf nodes are probabilities that the predicted class is "No".

Each data point follows a unique path in the tree and class is predicted using output probabilities.

Comment: Hi, Ayush, Thanks. So you mean the big word “Class NO” is not the root’s label but represents the output probability as “No”. However, the number at the leaf is negative, how to understand that? A probability cannot be negative.

Comment: You are right. Usually we have probabilities in the leaf nodes. Here, maybe [NA] values are causing this result, otherwise you should consider it logloss. That would explain it correctly.